# Change default route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7

I have this code in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
  public const HOME = '/home';
```

i have overridden this using `redirectTo` method

```
    public static function redirectTo($guard)
    {
       if($somecondition)
        {
         return $guard . '/route1';
        }
        else
        {
          return $guard . '/route2';
         }
        
    }
```

but it stills calls home. Using laravel 8

Comment: try `return \Redirect::to($guard . '/route2');`

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko Yes then also it redirect to`home` on removing condition

Comment: Is this - $somecondition - defined?

Comment: @T.Shah Yes it is already defined it want to override HOME constant on that condition

Comment: Is this for authentication? and are you using Breeze?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the **handle** method at **app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if ($somecondition) {
                return $guard . '/route1';
            } else {
                return $guard . '/route2';
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($guards as $guard) {     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {        return redirect($guard . '/route');      }      }` i have this code when i use condition, it is still executing the route passed in `RouteServiceProvider`